# Rexster / Blueprints, Neo4j and C++

Tags: c++, neo4j, tinkerpop, rexster

I need a C++ binding for Rexster by TinkerPop. Is there anything available?

The reason for this, is because I need a high performance way to communicate with a Neo4j databases in C++. The REST API is probably going to be too slow for me.

After reading this post, it seems that RexPro is a better approach than the old ZeroMQ binding.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/Lp3pbCLv_nw

ZeroMQ binding (2011): https://github.com/Squelsh/lightsocket

If you disagree, is there a better way to interface with Neo4j in C++ ?

If there isn't one available, would it be so difficult to write one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j only supports Java natively. The only other way to access is through the REST API, or exposing something on your own.

Things like RexPro are a good alternative, but it's still using some type of RESTful endpoint, and I do not see a C++ binding.

Can you share what you need the native Neo4j API for? Is this something that can be accomplished via Cypher or Gremlin, and you just have the data shipped back to you via the RESTful endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the Java API it is not a big problem to write a binary protocol or use other means of communication, see https://github.com/jexp/cypher_websocket_endpoint for example.

Answer (score 0):

I work with Java JNI and I'm thinking about writing a C++ wrapper for accessing an embedded Neo4J. Same interest - high performance access from C++. The idea then would be to define a C++ public API that wraps the JNI stuff that goes on when interfacing c++ to Neo4J Java classes. Any interest, let me know.